# Constructor in for loop

Tags: c++, oop, constructor

I have just started with OO and I have a question about constructors. This would just create the same object "Team a" over and over with a different parameter i, correct?

```
for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++) Team a (i); // construct teams
```

How can I create different "Teams", i.e. Team a, Team b ... Team h if I know how many teams there has to be? Can't the parameter i be the attribute and the name at the same time (Team 1, Team 2..)?

Thanks in advanced for any tip or help!

Pd: this is the constructor I'm using (if you need more code please write it in the comments):

```
public:
//constructors
Team(int n); // (this will set number to n and points, goals_scored, goals_lost to 0)
```

Comment: Store the teams in a `std::vector<Team>` and use `push_back(a);` inside the loop.

Comment: Yes, you can use the parameter like that. As pointed out, your current attempt creates and deletes `a` in the body of the loop because it is local. Create a vector outside the loop and push new teams into it.

Comment: Re: "create the same object...": this would create a **different** object `Team a` each time. The object that you get on the second pass through the loop has no connection whatsoever with the object you got on the first pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
std::vector<Team> teams;

for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    teams.emplace_back(i + 1); // makes Team(i + 1) in vector
```

**Note:** the `std::vector` uses *zero based indexing* so your team #1 is index 0:

```
teams[0]; // team #1
teams[1]; // team #2
teams[n]; // team #n + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You would like to use `map` from STL:

```
std::map <string, Team> Teams;
for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++)
{
  std::string noStr = std::to_string(i);
  std::string teamName = "Team " + noStr; // "Team 1", "Team 2", ..., "Team N"
  Teams[teamName] = Team(i); // Store Team object in the map 
}
```

Now you can access any team using its name :

```
// For team 5 object
Teams["Team 5"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm doing maps next week but will save this for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

1st question: yes it would produce n times a variable `a` of type `Team`. But(!) It is local to the for loop at each iteration. You wont be able to use them later.

2nd question: pure numbers cant be names.
This does not work:

```
int 1 = 1; // not(!) valid
```

You can use something like this:

```
int a_1 = 1 ;
int a_2 = 2;
```

But you can't produce this by a variable:

```
for (int i = 1; i < n+1; i++){
    int a_i = 1; // defines a local variable "a_i" 
    int i = i ;// not valid i is already defined
}
```

You should use a container (e.g. a vector) of teams.

Comment: Thanks for answering the questions, know I won't do the same mistake next time :)